# Distributing power to varying resistance

Tags: power-supply

Can a regulator be built to divide the output of  a DC power source to supply identical amperage, in the range of  1 to 5  Amps, to 16 individual conductive parts in an electrolytic solution

Said parts are connected to the system with varying contact resistance.  It will be required that voltage to each different location will be controlled to assure the amperage to each part is constant

The parts would be plated in an electrolytic solution. 
The desired end result will be the delivery of the same amount of charge (number of coulombs) to each part.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is a [constant-current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source), where the current is set, and the voltage varies according to load resistance.

[This paper](http://nzic.org.nz/ChemProcesses/metals/8G.pdf) describes a good overview of the entire [electroplating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroplating) process, including a blurb about current density and plating thickness. *"The current divided by the apparent area yields an average figure. Except for the simplest geometries of a cell, such as when the anode and cathode are concentric, the current is not uniform over the surface of an electrode."* So if you were hoping for a "magic current value" to make everything plate wonderfully, then it doesn't exist. What will help, is placing more anodes in or near the hard-to-plate areas, such as inside circles or tubes, depressions, cavities, etc.

Surprisingly, there is little info to be found about power supplies specifically for electroplating. There are a few big vendors, such as [Caswell](http://www.caswellplating.com/electroplating-anodizing/power-supplies.html) or [Mastech](http://www.mastechpowersupply.com/variable-dc-power-supply/plating-and-anodizing-rectifiers.html?page=all), and these may be fine for a commercial or industrial application. Some specialty supplies may be a "pulse" type, which either pulses the current on-of-on, or reverse the current altogether for a short time. There is some debate as to whether this may improve the resulting plate, and like everything else in electroplating, depends on many factors.

Comment: I had my motorcycle exhaust header chromed once. (If you ever do this, make sure the person doing it dip-cleans the part first - I cleaned it myself but didn't have the chemicals to chrome-plate, and just the drive there was enough to cause some nasty bubbles.) Anyways, they said the areas where the tubes converged probably wouldn't plate well, and they didn't. The only way to make it "perfect" would be to add more anodes in the hard-to-plate areas and set them up on independent current sources. More expense in set-up fees.

Answer (score 1):

If each part has a different resistance, then each part will need a different voltage to achieve the same current.  So you'll be able to do this, but not with one regulator - you'll need one per part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one unregulated power supply to drive multiple (adjustable) constant current sources.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE04az.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A simple way of doing it might be to use a lamp as a 'constant current' source on each circuit to balance out the currents. Not perfect, not efficient, but very simple and gives a bright indication of how each piece is doing. Would a 55 W, 12 or 24 V car / truck headlight bulb do the trick?

Comment: Not sure that a lamp could really be described as a constant current source.

Comment: @lcy: I know, but here's my thinking. An ideal current source has infinite output impedance so that, no matter what the load resistance is, its terminal voltage will rise or fall to maintain the set current. In this application I have no idea what the part-solution resistance is but let's say it varies between 0.1Ω and 0.25Ω. The 55 W lamp has an on resistance of V²/P = 144/55 = 2.6Ω. For a 12 V supply the current would vary between 4.4 A @ 0.1Ω and drop to 4.2 A @ 0.25 A. This is a variation of 5% for a 250% change in load resistance. Efficient? No. Good enough? Maybe!